# How to fix denied permission to access a directory if that directory was added during docker build?

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile, file-permissions, chown

I using the following `Dockerfile` to extend a docker image:

```
FROM solr:6.6

COPY --chown=solr:solr ./services-core/search/A12Core /A12Core/
```

Note that `solr:6.6` has a `USER solr` statement.

When running a container built from that Dockerfile I get a permission denied when trying to access a file or directory under `/A12Core`:

```
$ docker run -it 2f3c58f093e6 /bin/bash
solr@c091f0cd9127:/opt/solr$ cd /A12Core
solr@c091f0cd9127:/A12Core$ cd conf
bash: cd: conf: Permission denied
solr@c091f0cd9127:/A12Core$ ls -l
total 8
drw-r--r-- 3 solr solr 4096 Aug 31 14:21 conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 solr solr  158 Jun 28 14:25 core.properties
solr@c091f0cd9127:/A12Core$ whoami
solr
solr@c091f0cd9127:/A12Core$
```

What do I need to do in order to get permission to access the fiels and folders in the `/A12Core` directory?

Note that I'm running the docker build from windows 7. My docker version is `18.03.0-ce`.

Comment: This may help: [how do linux file permissions work](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+do+linux+file+permissions+work) and  [how do linux directory permissions work](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+do+linux+directory+permissions+work). Also see [Execute vs Read bit. How do directory permissions in Linux work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/21251/56041) on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had another answer here, which was wrong (but still solved your problem :), but now I see the typo in your Dockerfile. Let's take a look at this line.

```
COPY --chown=solr:solr ./services-core/search/A12Core /A12Core/
```

The `COPY` command checks if the target path in the container exists. If not, it creates it, before copying.

1. It takes `A12Core` from `./services-core/search`.
2. Then it checks if path `/A12Core` exists.
3. Obviously, it does not. So, the command creates it with permissions `root:root`.
4. Lastly, it copies contents of `A12Core` to newly created `A12Core`.

In the end your have everything in `/A12Core`, but it belongs to `root` and you can't access it.

Since `solr` docker image already sets `USER solr`, the way to go would be

```
RUN mkdir /A12Core
COPY ./services-core/search/A12Core /A12Core
```

As [the docs say](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user)

> The `USER` instruction sets the user name ... the user group ... for any `RUN`, `CMD` and `ENTRYPOINT` instructions that follow it in the `Dockerfile`.

Comment: When you copy a directory in a Dockerfile, docker copies the contents of the directory, not the directory itself. So step 4 in your answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

Your directory does not have execute permission:

```
drw-r--r-- 3 solr solr 4096 Aug 31 14:21 conf
```

Without that, you cannot cd into the directory according to Linux filesystem permissions. You can fix that in your host with a chmod:

```
chmod +x conf
```

If you perform this command inside your Dockerfile (with a `RUN` line), it will result in any modified file being copied to a new layer, so if you run this recursively, it could double the size of your image, hence the suggestion to fix it on your build host if possible.